# Best case time Complexity to check if the array is unsorted

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I am trying to find out the best case time complexity while checking if the given array is unsorted.

I think, this is the fastest way to check if array is sorted or unsorted and the time complexity should be O(n) for this one.

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) { 
  if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Only this will likely throw an error, when you are trying to access `a[i + 1]` for the _last_ array element ... the loop should run for `i < a.length - 1` only (or start at 1, and then compare with `a[i-1]` instead.)

Comment: Your code doesn't take account into the correct array bounds (condition should be `i + 1 < a.length`), and you should not return with `true` inside of the loop, because you should test all elements.

Comment: @CBroe The code _would_ be out of bounds (UB) for `a[i+1]` but it will never get beyond the first iteration.

Comment: This question is not asking for the fastest algorithm to find if an array is sorted, it is asking for best-case complexity. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it should be easy to call a question a total train wreck. The code block had a small error and it is updated. The logic of question needed an answer not the code block itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this takes `O(n)`, and it is [as fast as it gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989071/fastest-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-sorted).

---

Moreover, you need to change this:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```

to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
```

since you access `a[i + 1` and you do not want to go out of bounds. Furthermore, your return statements should be swapped.

Comment: This would be better: `for (i = 0; i + 1 < a.length; i++)`

Comment: Why @DAle? Please explain.

Comment: To avoid possible infinity loop in the case when `a.length == 0`

Comment: @DAle There's only a problem when `a.length-1` is unsigned and can thus underflow into a really big number. If it's signed, that would involve checking `0 < -1`, which is false, so the loop will break right away (this would be the case in Java, which this code looks like).

Comment: @Dukeling, thank you for a clarification! I know that this code looks like Java code and there is no such problem in Java. But there was a chance that this is some other language, and that's why I wrote 'possible'. I prefer to use `i + 1` form of this loop even in Java. Just don't want to enforce the reader to think about that signed/unsigned/underflow staff.

Answer (score 0):

The average and worst-case complexity for your algorithm to check if an array is unsorted  is `O(N)`.  But the **best-case complexity** is `O(1)`.

The best case occurs when the first two elements of the array are out of order.  This is detected in the first loop iteration, and takes a constant time irrespective of `N`.