# Method that recognized if a IEnumerable is sorted

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have this Extension method to check if a List of any type is sorted

```
public static bool IsSorted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    IEnumerable<T> expectedListASC = input.OrderBy(x => x);
    IEnumerable<T> expectedListDESC = input.OrderByDescending(x => x);
    return expectedListASC.SequenceEqual(input) || expectedListDESC.SequenceEqual(input);
}
```

But with large Lists it takes time. Is there a more efficient way to get the same result?

Comment: Why not just enumerate list and check if following element is always lesser/greater  then previous. It would be linear in time (and you can drop checking earlier if not sorted) - for unsorted lists it would be close to const time.

Comment: Consuming an enumerable multiple times is a) not guaranteed to be possible and b) not guaranteed to be consistent. If you want something *solidly* generic, your starting point shouldn't be `IEnumerable<T>`. Even if you change you code to use e.g. `ToList()` first, your caller still has these problems no matter what you returned. If the caller *needs* a sorted enumerable, just have them use `OrderBY` and accept that it may be redundant if the enumerable was already sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if an array is sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989071/fastest-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-sorted)

Comment: @FCin - That isn't a good duplicate in my opinion - the code is easier for a non-generic array of `int`s, and you don't look for both cases of ascending/descending order.

Comment: Grab the collections `IEnumerator<T>`, then grab the first two items, if they're equal (according to your rules), grab the next item and compare to the previous one. Keep doing this until you've got two where you can tell if which one is greater. Then use the knowledge of whether these two are in increasing or decreasing order to grab the rest of the elements and compare to the previous. This is going to be an `O(N)` operation.

Comment: "Sorted" and "ordered by the default comparison" is not necessarily the same... Also, consider to start with a type check for [`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534852(v=vs.110).aspx) before you compute anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a generic method that ought to detect whether the sequence is in increasing or decreasing order, and then checking if the rest of the collection follows suit.

It has **not** been fully tested, you should throw datasets to it left and right and write unit-tests if you decide to use this.

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

        bool? expectedToIncrease = null;
        using (var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            bool gotFirst = enumerator.MoveNext();
            if (!gotFirst)
                return true; // empty collection is ordered
            var first = enumerator.Current;
            T second = default(T);

            while (expectedToIncrease is null)
            {
                bool gotSecond = enumerator.MoveNext();
                if (!gotSecond)
                    return true; // only equal elements are ordered
                second = enumerator.Current;

                switch (comparer.Compare(first, second))
                {
                    case int i when i < 0:
                        expectedToIncrease = false;
                        break;

                    case int i when i > 0:
                        expectedToIncrease = true;
                        break;
                }

                if (expectedToIncrease is null)
                    first = second; // prepare for next round
            }

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (expectedToIncrease.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    if (comparer.Compare(second, enumerator.Current) < 0)
                        return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (comparer.Compare(second, enumerator.Current) > 0)
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ought to work:

```
public static bool IsSorted<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    if (input is IOrderedEnumerable<T>)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    T previous = default(T);
    bool previousSet = false;
    bool? comparisonOrder = null;
    foreach (var value in input)
    {
        if (!previousSet)
        {
            previous = value;
            previousSet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int comparisonResult = comparer.Compare(previous, value);
            if (comparisonResult != 0)
            {
                if (!comparisonOrder.HasValue)
                {
                    comparisonOrder = comparisonResult > 0;
                }
                else if (comparisonResult > 0 != comparisonOrder)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            previous = value;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It goes through each item whilst tracking the previous, and then uses the default comparer (as `.OrderBy()` would) to check if they are sorted. To allow for checking sorting in either direction, I store the result of the first non-zero comparison, and use that as a point to check.

As already noted in the comments, not all `IEnumerable`s are re-iterable, and re-iterating those that are can be costly, depending on the implementation of what is providing the `IEnumerable`. Also, consider the case of an `IEnumerable` that returns random numbers - each time you iterate it, it would give different values (assuming the seed wasn't the same each time).

Test on a sorted list of 50,000 items (5,000 iterations) revealed that:

- Lasse's took 2137 ms to determine if it was sorted.
- My method took 2348 ms to determine if the `IEnumerable` was sorted.
- MineR's took 2403 ms to return a result.

Comment: does this differ in ascending and descending?

Comment: It did, but it's fixed now, so it should check either. Lasse's is probably a little more efficient than mine, however.

Comment: One note on this - `comparer.Compare` may return any positive/negative number, so you should use `Math.Sign` to get just `1`, `-1`, or `0`.

Comment: @Kobi Thanks, fixed :)

Comment: Thanks for the performance measurement! Now I want to micro-optimize my code. :P

Answer (score 2):

I have included the below solution which only differs from the others in that you can specify a comparer, and it will tell you the order in which the collection is sorted.

```
public static class LinqHelpers
{
    [Flags]
    public enum SortDirections
    {
        NotSorted = 0,
        Ascending = 1,
        Descending = 2,
    }
    public static SortDirections GetSortDirection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

        bool isAsc = true;
        bool isDsc = true;
        bool isFirst = true;
        T last = default(T);
        foreach (var val in input)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                int cmp = comparer.Compare(last, val);
                if (cmp > 0) isAsc = false;
                if (cmp < 0) isDsc = false;
            }
            if (!isAsc && !isDsc) break;
            last = val;
        }
        int result = 0;
        if (isAsc) result |= (int)SortDirections.Ascending;
        if (isDsc) result |= (int)SortDirections.Descending;
        return (SortDirections)result;
    }
}
```

Some edge cases:

- If 0 elements, it is considered sorted in both directions.
- If 1 element, it is considered sorted in both directions.
- If all elements are the same, it is considered sorted in both directions.

Why is yours slow for large data sets? You are sorting the data, which is O(n log n). This problem need only be O(n).